# why table header click event not working to firing?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to sort my column using click event of column header.I am using angular js framework using filter **orderBy** .I saw a example which is working fine which is sort the column on click of header of column

http://plnkr.co/edit/aGAI6EmCwGyPKmFZAFb8?p=preview

I make a simple demo using above example try to sort my column on header click 
.When I click on header it gives me alert of index , reverse parameter along with image is also change but the column is not sorted
can we sort column using header click as shown in above example
here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/r22YnCILVSuWPrMnTnv2?p=preview

please click on any column header and see the alerts but column is not sorted why ?
Please increase the output window screen of plunker to see the outputs .

```
<header-row ng-transclude class="row rowclassheaderClass" style="padding-bottom:1%">
    <div class="col brd text-center brdleft_right gray-20 collapse-sm columnCss"
         ng-repeat="d in invoice_column_name | filter:{checked: true}">
        <sort-header label="{{d.label|uppercase}}" index="{{d.index}}"
                     sort-exp="setSort(idx, reverse)"></sort-header>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-10 text-center brd gray-20" ng-click="openSettingPopover($event)">
        <button class="button-icon icon ion-ios-more fntandbg"></button>
    </div>
</header-row>
```

**Any update..?**

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to re-invent the wheel.  There is a sortBy built directly into angular.

Take a look at
[docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

In particular the first example for a basic overview and then the second one (I have outlined in the code sample below) it does exactly what you are trying to achieve but in much less code.

> [View Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

```
<body ng-app="orderByExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <table class="friend">
    <tr>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="reverse=false;order('name', false)">Name</a>
        (<a href="" ng-click="order('-name',false)">^</a>)</th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('phone', reverse)">Phone Number</a></th>
      <th><a href="" ng-click="reverse=!reverse;order('age',reverse)">Age</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends">
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
```